# Trying to force WPF Ribbon to always show ribbon tab groups as collapsed (until the user opens them up)

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, ribbon

I am trying to force WPF Ribbon to always show ribbon tab groups as collapsed (until the user opens them up).
I defined a resource defining ribbon group size definitions with the group size definition of collapesed group. Then I am using that static resource to set GroupSizeDefinitions property of the style for a RibbonGroup. However, I do see some of the groups not in collapsed state. Do I miss something in my xaml?:

```
<ribbon:RibbonGroupSizeDefinitionBaseCollection x:Key="groupSizeDefinitions">
    <ribbon:RibbonGroupSizeDefinition IsCollapsed="True"/>
</ribbon:RibbonGroupSizeDefinitionBaseCollection>
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="groupItemsPanelTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonGroup}" BasedOn="{StaticResource RibbonControlStyle}">
    <Setter Property="QuickAccessToolBarId" Value="{Binding Label}" />
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Label}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ControlDataCollection}" />
    <Setter Property="ribbon:RibbonTwoLineText.Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource groupItemsPanelTemplate}"/>
    <Setter Property="GroupSizeDefinitions"  Value="{StaticResource groupSizeDefinitions}"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try doing it without using Style? Or using other layout panel, say DockPanel instead of StackPanel in ItemsPanelTemplate?

I was able to keep the ribbon group collapsed by doing this:

```
<ribbon:RibbonGroupSizeDefinitionBaseCollection x:Key="MyLayout">
      <ribbon:RibbonGroupSizeDefinition IsCollapsed="True" />
</ribbon:RibbonGroupSizeDefinitionBaseCollection>


<ribbon:RibbonGroup GroupSizeDefinitions="{StaticResource MyLayout}" >
      <ribbon:RibbonButton Command="{x:Static Commands.EditItem}" Label="Edit" />
      <ribbon:RibbonButton Command="{x:Static MyCommands.DeleteItem}" Label="Delete" />
</ribbon:RibbonGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks. but I am trying to do the same via styles, since all the groups have to be collapsed by default. Any idea why the same settings via style do not work? Ribbon's bug or did I miss anything?